# Input won't focus when element opens

Tags: jquery, gsap

Trying to get an input to focus when the parent container has the class open.

Code I have so far is:

```
$("#search-trigger").click(function(){
 $("input").focus(); 
});
```

Which, only works oddly when the element begins to close. So, I changed it to:

```
$("#search-trigger").click(function(){
  if(("#target-2").hasClass("open")){
    $("input").focus();
  }else{
  $("input").blur();}
});
```

Which doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/YWKPgm?editors=1010)

Comment: Please include all code needed to replicate the problem in the question itself (not just a codepen, fiddle etc). Better still use the snippets feature, press the <> button in  the editor to add the code like a codepen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the primary issue here was that the input wasn't done animating, so jQuery couldn't focus on it. The resolution would be to use TweenMax's `onComplete` event to focus on the element after the target was shown.

Note, though, that your original question didn't contain the animation code, so others on this site wouldn't have been able to help if they weren't willing to view your CodePen.

Here's the new JavaScript I made, though you can just modify your original code to use the `onComplete` function instead:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
  //remove active class from other triggers
  $('.trigger').not(this).removeClass('active');
  //toggle active class on this trigger
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  //get target element
  var target = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target-id'));
  //hide all elements of target class, except the current target
  if($('.target.open').not(target).size() > 0) {
    TweenMax.to($('.target.open').not(target), .2, {display:'none', y:'0%', autoAlpha:0});
    //remove open class from target elements that are now hidden
    $('.target.open').not(target).removeClass('open');
  }
  //if this element is now active
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    //show current target element
    TweenMax.to(target, .2, {display:'block', y:'100%', autoAlpha:1, onComplete:function() {
      //once animation is complete, if the target has an input, focus on that input
      if(target.find('input').size() > 0) {
        target.find('input').focus();
      }
    }});
    //indicate that this target class element is now open
    target.addClass('open');
  }
  //if the element is no longer active
  else {
    //hide the target
    TweenMax.to(target, .2, {display:'none', y:'0%', autoAlpha:0});
    //remove open class from newly hidden target element
    target.removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

And here's a CodePen right back at ya: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaLkYo

Comment: Yeap, it seems that it was an onComplete animation issue :) It seems however that this code breaks the design... if you click the trigger again, it should close the target div, but in this instance, it doesn't register the event.

Comment: The callback ensures the animation will be done before focus. I did not even check at TeenMax, wich is a lib I don't know. Your answer is obviously better that mine. And you "cleaned" OP code. You deserve the accepted answer. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

I [updated your CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XjodZr?editors=1010).

You have an animation going on...
I didn't checked how it is achieved closely, since an external lib (TweenMax) is doing it.

But, seeing the animation, I thought about *delay*.
And this is my answer.

You can't `focus` an element that has `display` setted to `none`.
This display is setted to `block` or `inline-block` by your animation somewhere...

I found that a 10ms delay was enought in this case.
And just to be sure we select the right `input`, because even if there is only one in that example... Your site will have more for sure.

I specified it to be a *children of a sibling* of the clicked element.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// This is the code for the input focus
$("#search-trigger").click(function(){
    var searchInput = $(this).siblings().find("input");
    setTimeout(function(){
        searchInput.focus();
    },10);
});
```

Comment: There it is! Was unaware that you cannot focus a field in a hidden container.

Comment: I still suggest using the onComplete function from TweenMax, as it provides a callback. setTimeout could technically take longer than the specified 10 milliseconds to kick in, and could potentially (though not likely) allow another user click before completing the action. More on why setTimeout delays could take longer than intended: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Answer (score 0):

If you have many inputs on your page than give specific one that you want to focus ID and call it by ID like this:

```
 $("input#my-input").focus();
```

Comment: why not just an id in the selector?

Comment: Just an ID *would* suffice - but I don't think this will answer the question. If you checked OP's CodePen link, you'd see there's only one input on the page, so an element selector is not the issue in this case.

Comment: Even if you reference the element's id, it still doesn't work